# Capture Monday's Date

Tags: c#, date

I need to be able to (on any given day of the week) capture the upcoming Mondays date.  If this syntax is run on a Monday, I need to capture the next Monday's date in the format of mm.dd.yyyy.  I know how to just capture the date in that format, but how would I go about capturing the upcoming Monday?

Comment: What day is it now? How many days until the next Monday? DateTime.Add.

Answer (score 1):

This is a trivial problem. A simple loop will do it, but there are probably a bunch of more optimal solutions:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;

    internal class Program
    {       
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var arbitraryDate = DateTime.Today;

            do
            {
                arbitraryDate = arbitraryDate.AddDays(1);
            }
            while (arbitraryDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday);

            Console.WriteLine(arbitraryDate.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy"));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "Simple," "easy to understand," and "good enough" is ... good.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic extension method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the first occurrence of the specified weekday following (or on) the current System.DateTime object.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="currentDate">The current date</param>
/// <param name="dayOfWeek">The weekday to find</param>
/// <param name="includeCurrentDate">Include the current date as a valid result</param>
/// <returns>The first date of the weekday after (or on) the current System.DateTime object.</returns>
public static DateTime NextWeekday(this DateTime currentDate, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, bool includeCurrentDate)
{
    int daysInWeek = 7;
    int offset = includeCurrentDate ? 0 : 1;
    int days = (dayOfWeek - currentDate.AddDays(offset).DayOfWeek + daysInWeek) % daysInWeek;
    return currentDate.AddDays(days + offset);
}
```